# Define reverse using fold left

Tags: ocaml, higher-order-functions, fold

I have this definition of fold left

```
let rec fold_left f lst u = match lst with
                            | [] -> u
                            |(h::t) -> fold_left f t ( f h u)
```

I have to define reverse using the fold_left above. I currently have

```
let reverse l1 = fold_left (fun x y -> y::x) l1 []
```

but I keep getting this error

```
Error: This expression has type 'a list
       but an expression was expected of type 'a
       The type variable 'a occurs inside 'a list
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why redefining fold_left and not using List.fold_left?

Comment: Some teachers do that to make students understand how it works. My only remark would be that, for `fold_left`, the accumulator is the second parameter, not the third one, so you might be confused when using `List.fold_left`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have the accumulator and next item turned around (`y::x` instead of `x::y`). This works:

```
let reverse l1 = fold_left (fun x y -> x::y) l1 []
```

Comment: You can also write `let reverse l = fold_left List.cons l []`